# roscore failing

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just updated my system (System76, Onx Pro) with the latest ubuntu16 software (software updater) .Now when I run roscore  it just hangs. I get the following if I ctl-c. Any idea on what is going on greatly appreciated. Update applied Aug 8.

```
richard@rjn:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/richard/.ros/log/30066d64-7d41-11e7-91a0-0028f87b9f9e/roslaunch-rjn-3059.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore", line 70, in <module>
    roslaunch.main(['roscore', '--core'] + sys.argv[1:])
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 307, in main
    p.start()

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 226, in _start_infrastructure
    self._start_server()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 177, in _start_server
    self.server.start()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 376, in start
    code, msg, val = ServerProxy(self.uri).get_pid()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1283, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1311, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1459, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 836, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 566, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
richard@rjn:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268428/roscore-failing/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I seem to have had an issue with setting my ROS_IP address. Sorry for the panic.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0